# Adding shp files to PostGIS in QGIS 2

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.0

I followed [this](http://www.jaloonz.com/2012/08/installing-postgis-201-on-ubuntu-1204.html) tutorial to set up Postgresql 9.1 and PostGIS 2 on my Ubuntu Server 12.04. I also installed pgAdmin III on my Windows 7 client. I set up a database landarch and user chadmwade, granting all privleges. I am able to connect to the postgres and the landarch databases with pgAdmin III and in QGIS.

I am getting the following error when attempting up add [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfcvrd4azci393b/OC_Municipalities.zip) shp file to the database. Is someone able to guide me in addressing this error? I haven't had much luck with Google.

[image: this]

Comment: Have you tried DB Manager instead of SPIT? I thought SPIT was deprecated anyway.

Comment: @underdark: I did now and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new [DB Manager](http://www.qgis.org/de/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_db_manager.html) it is *"part of QGIS core and intends to replace the SPIT Plugin and additionally to integrate all other database formats supported by QGIS in one user interface. "*

Amongst other features it has a nice "Import layer/file" button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably your geometry column is defined as "multipolygon" and your shapefile maybe has only geometry type "polygon".

In your insert-statement use `st_multi(your_geometry_column)`, where instead of `your_geometry_column` you have to enter the name of your geometry column.

Comment: The shp files do not have a existing geometry column form what I can see in the attribute tables. Also I am doing this through the GUI for the SPIT plugin associated with QGIS 2.0.

Comment: @LandArch - In general, the geometry column for an ESRI Shapefile is named `Shape`, so that is what you would enter.